# Alternative to Fernet Encyption Algorithm w.o Salt

Tags: python, encryption, encryption-symmetric, fernet

Hi I am new to encryption algorithms and am a little confused by the terminology and what to choose for which situation. For now I don't need the most secure algorithm but it should have the following properties:

- A shared secret key, that encrypts/decrypts the message (two way).
- The Cipher should be the same if same text for encryption has been used.

I used the Fernet algorithm in Python, however the Ciphertext is always different. and therefore not suitable for my needs. Is there an algorithm similar to Fernet but without the Salt?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the [cryptography](https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/) module (which you should): Instead of using `generate_key()`, build the key and pass it to the `Fernet` constructor.

Check this link for the precise example: https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/#using-passwords-with-fernet

Additionally, check https://www.crypto101.io/ if you haven't yet.

Comment: That link shows a method that will result in different ciphertexts for the same method due to the random salt, violating constraint #2. Making the salt a constant or getting rid of it solves that problem but adds a new one: it enables precomputation attacks (e.g. rainbow tables) against the password.

Comment: That's right!. Exchanging the key + salt is required (the salt can be 0), which is as risky (or as secure) as sharing the secret key in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's no ready algorithm do what you're asking for "at lease that what I know".
But in the past I've wrote a GUI chat room with a real server and real clients in python.
And I've wrote a basic encryption/decryption algorithm to pass the data encrypted "like messages".
you can use it if you want cuz I've never used that server I made it just for fun ;).

The algorithm:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

CODES_KEY = b'LYsrKDiTRNJDm3g_h25GW0uyUzPTk8l8G02hcPM_d_U='

def encryption(msg):
    '''
    Encryption Func
    '''

    class RSA:
        '''
        RSA Encryption Func
        '''
        def __init__(self):
            self.e = self.d = self.p = self.q = self.phi = 0

        def __egcd(self, a, b):
            if a == 0:
                return (b, 0, 1)
            g, y, x = self.__egcd(b % a, a)
            return (g, x - (b // a) * y, y)

        def __modinv(self, a, m):
            g, x, _ = self.__egcd(a, m)
            if g != 1:
                raise Exception('modular inverse does not exist')
            return x % m

        def encrypt(self, m, key_pair=None):
            '''
            Encrypting Func
            '''
            if key_pair is None:
                key_pair[0] = self.e
                key_pair[1] = self.n

            return pow(m, key_pair[0], key_pair[1])

        def generate_keys(self, p, q, e=3):
            '''
            Generating Keys Func
            '''
            self.p = p
            self.q = q

            self.n = self.p * self.q
            self.phi = (self.p - 1) * (self.q - 1)
            self.e = e
            self.d = self.__modinv(self.e, self.phi)

            if self.phi % self.e == 0:
                raise Exception('invalid values for p and q')

        def get_public_key(self):
            '''
            Getting PublicKey Func
            '''
            return self.e, self.n

    rsa = RSA()
    # Two 1024-bit primes
    rsa.generate_keys(17055899557196527525682810191339089909014331959812898993437334555169285087976951946809555356817674844913188193949144165887100694620944167618997411049745043243260854998720061941490491091205087788373487296637817044103762239946752241631032791287021875863785226376406279424552454153388492970310795447866569138481,
                      171994050316145327367864378293770397343246561147593187377005295591120640129800725892235968688434055779668692095961697434700708550594137135605048681344218643671046905252163983827396726536078773766353616572531688390937410451433665914394068509329532352022301339189851111636176939179510955519440490431177444857017)

    int_message = []

    for i in msg:

        int_message.append(ord(i))

    codes = []

    for i in int_message:

        codes.append(len(str(i)))

    message = int(''.join([str(x) for x in int_message]))

    # Encrypting
    encrypted_message = rsa.encrypt(message, key_pair=rsa.get_public_key())

    f = Fernet(CODES_KEY)
    encrypted_codes = f.encrypt(str(codes).encode())

    return encrypted_message, encrypted_codes

def decryption(msg, codes):
    '''
    Decryption Func
    '''

    class RSA:
        '''
        RSA Decryption Func
        '''
        def __init__(self):
            self.e = self.d = self.p = self.q = self.phi = 0

        def __egcd(self, a, b):
            if a == 0:
                return (b, a, 1)
            g, y, x = self.__egcd(b % a, a)
            return (g, x - (b // a) * y, y)

        def __modinv(self, a, m):
            g, x, _ = self.__egcd(a, m)
            if g != 1:
                raise Exception('modular inverse does not exist')
            return x % m

        def decrypt(self, c, key_pair=None):
            '''
            Decrypting Func
            '''
            if key_pair is None:
                key_pair[0] = self.d
                key_pair[1] = self.n

            return pow(c, key_pair[0], key_pair[1])

        def generate_keys(self, p, q, e=3):
            '''
            Generating Keys Func
            '''
            self.p = p
            self.q = q

            self.n = self.p * self.q
            self.phi = (self.p - 1) * (self.q - 1)
            self.e = e
            self.d = self.__modinv(self.e, self.phi)

            if self.phi % self.e == 0:
                raise Exception('invalid values for p and q')

        def get_private_key(self):
            '''
            Getting Private Key Func
            '''
            return self.d, self.n

    rsa = RSA()
    # Two 1024-bit primes
    rsa.generate_keys(17055899557196527525682810191339089909014331959812898993437334555169285087976951946809555356817674844913188193949144165887100694620944167618997411049745043243260854998720061941490491091205087788373487296637817044103762239946752241631032791287021875863785226376406279424552454153388492970310795447866569138481,
                      171994050316145327367864378293770397343246561147593187377005295591120640129800725892235968688434055779668692095961697434700708550594137135605048681344218643671046905252163983827396726536078773766353616572531688390937410451433665914394068509329532352022301339189851111636176939179510955519440490431177444857017)

    # Decrypting
    f = Fernet(CODES_KEY)
    # set_trace()
    decrypted_message = str(rsa.decrypt(int(msg), key_pair=rsa.get_private_key()))
    decrypted_codes = f.decrypt(codes).decode()

    decrypted_message = list(decrypted_message)

    original_codes = []

    for i in decrypted_codes:

        if i not in ['[', ']', ',', ' ']:
            original_codes.append(int(i))

    original_message = ""

    for _, value in enumerate(original_codes):

        handler = ""
        for i in decrypted_message[:value]:
            handler += i

        original_message += chr(int(handler))
        decrypted_message = decrypted_message[value:]

    return original_message

def main():

    message = "Hi, This is a secret message"
    encrypted_message, encrypted_codes = encryption(message)
    decrypted_message = decryption(encrypted_message, encrypted_codes)
    print(decrypted_message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Sorry if it's a mess but I'm just 17 years old bro :) !
Maybe you can optimize it more I've wrote this when i was new to python.
you can always generate new "CODES_KEY" by running this in python:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
f = Fernet
print(f.generate_key())
```

EDIT: I wrote this as an RSA but then changed the code, this is why it's named RSA but it's not :)